# How do I render this Django form?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, django-forms

I have a form where a user checks whether or not they own items from a particular brand. When the box is checked, a textbox appears beneath the checked item to take a product review.

My `models.py` looks like:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    owned_brand = BooleanField(default=False)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Product(models.Model):        
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, unique=True)
    #Other fields that we'll ignore for this exercise go here...
    product_review = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I want something like this pseudocode:

```
for each brand in Brand.entry.all():
    display form for that brand
```

How would I do that in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, I don't understand why you have a unique foreignkey. The idea of foreignkey is to create a ManyToOne relationship (each brand can have multiple products). But, for some reason, you added unique=True, which de facto forces it to be a sort of OneToOne relationship. Now, there is a reason that functionality is available to you, to quote the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

> Conceptually, this [one-to-one relationship] is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.

But then, I don't think that's what you're looking for, it seems like you *do* want to have a normal foreign key, so drop the unique=True.

Now for the problem at hand, if I understand you correctly, you want to fetch all the forms for each product for a certain brand. I don't fully understand where you want all this to happen so I wrote it like a view function:

```
def get_formes(request, brand_pk):
    products = Brand.objects.get(pk=brand_pk).product_set.all()
    forms = [ProductForm(instance=p) for p in products]

    return render_to_response('whateva.html', {'forms': forms})
```

That's assuming you are using a ModelForm. If not, you can use initial to tell the form what data to take from each product (for example ProductForm(initial={'name': p.name}) and so on). Then in the template you do this:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    <form>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

As a final note, I strongly recommend you change your field names. Why does brand need a field called brand_name? It's already a table of brands, the model is called Brand, wouldn't it make more sense to just call it name? Same thing goes for owned_brand, which should be just owned and product_review which should be just review